# Parsing a JSON in SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parsing

I want to parse my JSON data using SpringBoot. However, I am facing some issues in doing so.
For example, say my Input JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "XYZ",
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "Male Item" : {
        "property1": "abc",
        "property2" : "xxx"
    }
}
```

However, if say, my input have this structure:

```
{
    "name": "XYZ",
    "gender" : "FEMALE",
    "Female Item" : {
        "property3": "abcd",
        "property4" : "xffxx"
    }
}
```

If gender is coming as Male, then based on that, user would be sending me different properties than the user whose gender is Female. So, while parsing, if I make a User Class, then how my object mapper will decide which properties to pick?

Comment: Why are they different? you already have the gender

Comment: Yes, say in my Input, if gender is coming as Male, then based on that, user would be sending me different properties than the user whose gender is Female.
So, while parsing, if I make a User Class, then how my object mapper will decide which properties to pick. I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SerializedName` is the key here to solve this.
Here, how would I implement it:

Pojo Class `UserResponse.java`

```
class UserResponse {
        private String name;
        private String gender;
        @SerializedName("Male Item")
        private Map<String, String> maleProp;
        @SerializedName("Female Item")
        private Map<String, String> femaleProp;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getMaleProp() {
            return maleProp;
        }

        public void setMaleProp(Map<String, String> maleProp) {
            this.maleProp = maleProp;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getFemaleProp() {
            return femaleProp;
        }

        public void setFemaleProp(Map<String, String> femaleProp) {
            this.femaleProp = femaleProp;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UserResponse{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                    ", male=" + maleProp +
                    ", female=" + femaleProp +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Utils Function to read from stream/string and then converting it to pojo

```
private static UserResponse jsonToPojo(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(file));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonReader, UserResponse.class);
}
```

This is how would i call, for simplicity i am using `main` method;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(jsonToPojo("male.json"));
        System.out.println(jsonToPojo("female.json"));
}
```

Output would be:

```
UserResponse{name='XYZ', gender='MALE', male={property1=abc, property2=xxx}, female=null}
UserResponse{name='XYZ', gender='FEMALE', male=null, female={property3=abcd, property4=xffxx}}
```